# Poincare-Type Inequalities

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Right now I am in a lecture for numerical PDE, I come along the following Poincare-Type ineqalities and I have trouble to understand / prove them myself.

---

**Theorem** Let $\Omega$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain and $\Gamma \subset \partial \Omega$ with positive measure. Then for all $v \in H^1(\Omega)$ such that $\mathrm{tr}_\Gamma(v)=0$ we have
$$||v|| _ {L^2(\Omega)}^2\leq C||\nabla{v}|| _ {L^2(\Omega)}^2$$
for some constant $C>0$ wich is independent of $v$.  Further, assuming  a general $v\in H^1(\Omega)$ we have
$$||v|| _ {L^2(\Omega)}^2\leq D \left( ||\nabla v|| _ {L^2(\Omega)}^2+ ||\mathrm{tr} _ \Gamma u|| _ {L^2(\Gamma)}^2 \right)$$
for a constant $D>0$ independent of $v$.

---

I was able to show the first inequality if $\Gamma=\partial \Omega$, because then $v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ so we can just use partial integration for a function $u \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$  and we obtain
\begin{align*}
||u|| _ {L^2(\Omega)}^2&=\int _ \Omega1 \cdot u^2(x) dx =  \int _ \Omega \partial _ ix _ i\cdot u^2(x)dx=-2 \int _ \Omega x_i  u(x)  \partial _ i u(x)dx \newline
&\leq 2 C(\Omega)  \int _ \Omega  u(x)\partial_i u(x) dx\leq 2 C(\Omega) ||u|| _ {L^2(\Omega)} ||\partial _i u|| _ {L^2(\Omega)},
\end{align*}
for $C(\Omega)=|| \Omega || _ \infty$. Therefore we have
$$|| u || _ {L^2(\Omega)} \leq 2 C(\Omega) ||\partial _i u|| _ {L^2(\Omega)}.$$
Then summation over $i=1,\dots,n$ yields
$$||u|| _ {L^2(\Omega)}^2\leq \frac {4C(\Omega)^2} {n^2}  ||\nabla u || _ {L^2(\Omega)}^2.$$
Finally using the denseness $C_0^\infty(\Omega) \subset H^1_0(\Omega)$ we know that the above equation also holds for $v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$.

However, for $\Gamma \neq \partial \Omega$ I could not prove the statement. I was hoping that we maybe have in this context, that $C_0^\infty$ would again be dense in {$  v \in H^1(\Omega)\mid \mathrm{tr}_\Gamma =0  $}. But I do not think that this statement is true, but in case it is, then we could prove the statement in a similar manner as befor.

For the second statement, I was hoping that we could split the function $v = v_1 + v_2$ such that $\mathrm{tr}_\Gamma v_2 = 0$ and then apply the first theorem on something like
$$||v || _ {L^2(\Omega)}^2\leq ||v_1|| _ {L^2(\Omega)}^2+ ||v_2|| _ {L^2(\Omega)}^2.$$
However, this attempt was not successful.

For any help, tricks, advice or reverence I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove it using the classical proof by contradiction.

Assume the formula is false, then there exists a sequence $v_n$ such that $\|v_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)} = 1$ but $\|\nabla v_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \to 0$. Since $v_n$ is bounded in $H^1(\Omega)$ uniformly in $n$, up to extraction of subsequence, it converges weakly in $H^1$ to some function $v\in H^1(\Omega)$.

By the Rellich-Kondrachov compact embedding theorem, this implies that $v_n\to v$ in $L^2$ and so $\|v\|_{L^2} = 1$.

But since $\nabla v_n \to 0$ in $L^2$, $\nabla v = 0$ in the sense of distributions, and so $v$ is constant on any connected components of $\Omega$. Hence, if every connected component of $\Omega$ has a positive subset $\Gamma$ with positive measure such that $v=0$ on $\Gamma$, this constant is $0$ and so $v=0$, contradicting the fact that $\|v\|_{L^2} = 1$.

In particular, your result as stated holds if $\Omega$ is connected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I get the idea if we have a positive subset $\Gamma \subset \Omega$. However,  here we only have  a positive subset $\Gamma \subset \partial \Omega$. Which is has zero measure w.r.t. $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$. How can we adapt the idea in this setting?

Comment: @Salfalur Since $\Omega$ is connected, the proof provided above shows that $v$ is constant in $\Omega$, say $v = a$ a.e. for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$. In particular, since $v = 0$ on $\Gamma$, and since $\Gamma$ has positive measure, it follows that $v = 0$ a.e. in $\Omega$, which finishes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove that
$$\Vert u\Vert_{L^{2}(\Omega)}\leqslant C\left(\Vert\nabla u\Vert_{L^{2}(\Omega)}+\lvert\varphi(u)\lvert\right)$$
for any $u\in H^{1}(\Omega)$ by contradiction. Where $\varphi(u)=\int_{\Gamma}u\mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$ is a bounded linear functional in $H^{1}(\Omega)$ (by the trace theorem). Since $\varphi(c)\ne 0$ for any constant $c\ne 0$.

Comment: And $\lvert\varphi(u)\lvert\leqslant C\Vert u\Vert_{L^{2}(\Gamma)}$, that's your second problem.