Poincare inequalities with zero mean boundary traces
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded smooth domain and $\Gamma \subset \partial \Omega$ be a measurable part such that $|\Gamma| := \text{meas}_{(d-1)} \Gamma > 0$. For any
$$
w \in \widetilde{H}^1_\Gamma(\Omega) := \left\{ w \in H^1(\Omega) \ \middle|\  \frac{1}{|\Gamma|} \int_\Gamma w \, ds = 0 \right\},
$$
we have two estimates for the $L^2(\Omega)$ norm of $w$
$$
\left\|w\right\|_{2,\Omega} \leq C \|\nabla w\|_{2,\Omega}
$$
and for its trace on $\Gamma$
$$
\|w\|_{2,\Gamma} \leq C \|\nabla w\|_{2,\Omega}. 
$$
I found these in the article "Poincaré Type Inequalities for Vector
Functions with Zero Mean Normal
Traces on the Boundary and Applications
to Interpolation Methods". Do we have a reference for the proof or the original article of these?

you can try the standard proof by contradiction as in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4824591/
